# I am unable to identify my wireless adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

I have been struggling to identify the wireless adapter on my Linux machine.

The problem is when I press the control panel in the upper right with the volume and the ethernet settings there is no wireless internet option.

What I have tried:

I first went to the Software & Updates interface and switched to Main Server under Ubuntu Software.
Then I was able to get a Realtek Semiconductor Corp.: Unknown driver with two options under it. One of them saying "Do not use the device". I selected the other option: "Using dkms source for the r8812au network driver from rtl8812au-dkms." I press apply changes and reboot my computer and nothing happens.

After this happened I attempted to install the rtl8812au-dkms package off of github. The when I would build all of the files I got many errors, so I could not install them.

The next thing I try is to find the name of my wireless adapter using lspci.
lspci returns:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a308 (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Then I run some commands that only return information on the wireless adapter. I run the following commands:

```
$ lspci -vvnn | grep Network
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

Nothing is returned.
I am not sure if this means there is no wireless adapter or if it means something else. I used to run windows 10 on this device and was able to connect to wireless networks, so I know that it has a wireless adapter.

Because I am certain I have a wireless adapter I figured that WLAN could be disabled in BIOS. I go into BIOS and there is an option for Realtek LAN which is enabled. There is no option for WLAN. If bios does not show a WLAN option is there not a wireless adapter on my computer?

I know that there is a wireless adapter, because it worked on the same machine running windows.

I have two questions:

How can I identify my wireless adapter?
How can I install the right driver for my wireless adapter?

Comment: You probably have one of those internal wifi modules that look like they work over PCI but are actually internally connected via USB. Have you tries `lsusb`?

Comment: Usually when I want to identify hardware, I will check the device itself for identification like serial numbers. If it is an integrated component in a laptop or prebuilt PC, use the model number and search for documentation online.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`